# Let $(n,h)\in G = N \rtimes H$. Is it true that $\mathrm{ord}(n,h)=\mathrm{lcm}(\mathrm{ord}(n),\mathrm{ord}(h))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a group which is the (outer) semi-direct product of groups $N\rtimes H$. $n\in N,h\in H$. Is that true that the order of $(n,h)$ in $G$ is equal to the lcm of $\mathrm{ord}(n)$ and $\mathrm{ord}(h)$ ?

If it's not true, what may $\mathrm{ord}((n,h))$ be ? i. e. $\mathrm{ord}(n)\cdot\mathrm{ord}(h)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them is true. Take $G$ to be the dihedral group of order $2n$, so you can see it as the semi direct product of $N=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and  $H=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Take any  non trivial rotation $\sigma$ and any symmetry $\tau$. Then the order of $\sigma\tau$ is $2$ (since it is again a symmetry).

If you really want the interpretation in terms of semi-direct product, take $(\bar{m},\tilde{1})$ , where $\bar{m}$ is not trivial.

Comment: You might want to read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1)